# Keep getting element is not attached to the page document

Tags: python, selenium

I am running the following code to verify the text on the page:

```
def verifyText(self, Text):
    try:
       self.switchToFrame(*MainPageLocatars.FRAMEONE)
       self.switchToFrame(*MainPageLocatars.SUBLISTFRAME)
    except:
       pass
    self.row.find_element_by_xpath(ListViewLocatars.VERIFYTEXT % Text)
```

I tried adding time.sleep(2) after every step but it is still giving me an error when I run this function ->> Keep getting element is not attached to the page document error at this line of code

```
self.row.find_element_by_xpath(ListViewLocatars.VERIFYTEXT % Text)
```

I am calling the function here, where should i redefine it?

```
 listview = ListView(self.driver, 'First')
 listview.verifyText("comp1")
```

note that row is a parent:

```
self.row = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(ListViewLocatars.ROWPARENT % INDEX_MAP[index])
```

This is how I define the function:

```
class ListView(Page):

    def __init__(self, driver, index):

        if index not in INDEX_MAP:
            raise ValueError("Invalid index %s" % index)

        self.driver = driver

        try:
            self.row = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(ListViewLocatars.ROWPARENT % INDEX_MAP[index])
        # used for VerifyText function only
        except:
            self.row = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(ListViewLocatars.TEXTPARENT % INDEX_MAP[index])


    def verifyText(self, Text):
        try:
            self.switchToFrame(*MainPageLocatars.FRAMEONE)
            self.switchToFrame(*MainPageLocatars.SUBLISTFRAME)
        except:
            pass
        self.row.find_element_by_xpath(ListViewLocatars.VERIFYTEXT % Text)
```

here is full code:

```
# all locaters for this class are defined here only
class ListView(Page):

    def __init__(self, driver, index):

        if index not in INDEX_MAP:
            raise ValueError("Invalid index %s" % index)

        self.driver = driver

        try:
            self.row = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(ListViewLocatars.ROWPARENT % INDEX_MAP[index])
        # used for VerifyText function only
        except:
            self.row = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(ListViewLocatars.TEXTPARENT % INDEX_MAP[index])

    @property       
    def row(self):
        return self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(ListViewLocatars.ROWPARENT % INDEX_MAP[index])


    def verifyText(self, Text):
        try:
            self.switchToFrame(*MainPageLocatars.FRAMEONE)
            self.switchToFrame(*MainPageLocatars.SUBLISTFRAME)
        except:
            pass
        self.row.find_element_by_xpath(ListViewLocatars.VERIFYTEXT % Text)
```

It is now giving me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "autoLoaderTest.py", line 56, in test02_AutoLoaderSubCompany
    listview = ListView(self.driver, 'First')
  File "C:\Users\cverma\Desktop\SOAPProject\mainPage.py", line 44, in __init__
    self.row = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(ListViewLocatars.TEXTPARENT % INDEX_MAP[index])
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: This might be because page was updated since time you've declared `row` element, so you cannot use it anymore, but need to re-define it again

Comment: @Andersson, where do I need to redefine it? Pls see my updated question

Comment: show what is `row`, how you define it

Comment: @Andersson, its a parent xpath. I have edited my question

Comment: That's the problem: you've defined `self.row` somewhere, then you do some actions that forces page to refresh or lead to page redirection and you want to call `self.row` element which is attached to previous page, but not new one. You should try to define it as `@property` so you will re-define element each time you call property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simplified version of how `StaleElementReferenceException` can be triggered and how to avoid it.

I suppose your code works like below:

```
self.row = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(ListViewLocatars.ROWPARENT % INDEX_MAP[index])
# Now your self.row is accessible. You can use it
self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@type="text"]').send_keys('some data')
# This action could trigger page refresh
# Now your self.row is not accessible as it was found on previous page
self.row.find_element_by_xpath(ListViewLocatars.VERIFYTEXT % Text)
# Here comes StaleElementReferenceException
```

How you can avoid it:

```
@property
def row(self):
    return self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(ListViewLocatars.ROWPARENT % INDEX_MAP[index])

def verifyText(self, Text):
   try:
       self.switchToFrame(*MainPageLocatars.FRAMEONE)
       self.switchToFrame(*MainPageLocatars.SUBLISTFRAME)
    except:
       pass
    self.row.find_element_by_xpath(ListViewLocatars.VERIFYTEXT % Text)
    # only now self.row is defined and even if page refreshed
    # next time you call self.row, element will be re-defined
```

Comment: should I define it on top on __init__ ? I tried to do this but it is giving me an error
TypeError: 'property' object is not callable

Comment: This might be because you try to use it as method- `self.row()` while you should use property only like `self.row`, without `()`. You shoudn't define it inside `__init__()`

Comment: This is how i defined it. I have updated my question again.

Comment: Remove `try`/`except` block. Now it's redundant

Comment: No, I mean remove this declaration `self.row = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(ListViewLocatars.TEXTPARENT % INDEX_MAP[index])` at all- you don't need it now

Comment: sorry I am new to this, now it says index not defined

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137370/discussion-between-andersson-and-user7242550).